# How can I pass the data from view to another activity?

Tags: android

I have used CardView inside a RecyclerView in horizontal manner. Now what I want to do is, when user click on a card then the data which I have putted into the intent with the help of `putExtra` function should be passed to the next activity. 
Here is the code

```
public class SectionListDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionListDataAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {

private List<Section> itemsList;
private Context mContext;


public SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, List<Section> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_single_card, null);
    SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

    Section singleItem = itemsList.get(i);

    holder.tvTitle.setText(singleItem.getName());
    holder.tvAuthor.setText(singleItem.getAuthorname());
    holder.tvPremium.setText(singleItem.getPremium());

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(singleItem.getImage()
            .into(holder.itemImage);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
}

public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView tvTitle, tvAuthor, tvPremium;

    protected ImageView itemImage;


    public SingleItemRowHolder(final View view) {
        super(view);

        this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle1);
        this.tvAuthor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle2);
        this.tvPremium = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSubText1);
        this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);


        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BooksDescription.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", NavigationDrawer.ID.get());


                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }

}

}
```

Here in the line `intent.putExtra("id", NavigationDrawer.ID);` NavigationDrawe.ID having 20 integer data. Now which function should I use to get the data of only those card which is clicked.

Comment: int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);  Put this in another activity.

Comment: Use OnBindViewholder so that your will get the position of current componant.

Comment: Bro i have to put the data regarding the click on the card view. What to be added in putExtra function ? Because NavigationDrawer.ID  variable is giving 20 integer data. How can i come to know which data is the data of clicked card view

Comment: Use ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition() to know the currently clicked position, then retrieve the appropriate Section in itemsList at that position and pass it as Intent extra.

Comment: share your SingleItemRowHolder.xml file which hold design TextView and ImageView I'll help you

Comment: It is a row holder class of recycle view.

Comment: @fazeelzama I mean share xml code where you define TextView and ImageView

Comment: use clicklistener in onBindViewHolder .